# Passing variables in Query string in tsx file (react +typescript)

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, react, typescript

I am trying to pass plainid and id as a parameter in query string in URL.

```
{planid = item.planId}
        { id =item.id}
<td><a href="https://tasks.office.com/credentinfotech.com/en-GB/Home/Planner#/plantaskboard? planId=`${planid}`&taskId=`${id}`" >{item.title}</a></td>
        <td>{moment(item.startDateTime).format('MM/DD/YYYY ')}</td>
        <td>{moment(item.dueDateTime).format('MM/DD/YYYY')}</td>
```

I am new to React suggest any way so that I can pass variables in query string in the `.tsx` file.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<a href={"https://tasks.office.com/credentinfotech.com/en-GB/Home/Planner#/plantaskboard?planId=" + planid + "&taskId=" + id}></a>
```

Comment: Hi @abhishek, did you try this? does this answers your question? If Yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it will help others to find the correct answer easily. It will also remove this question from "Unanswered questions" list

Answer (score 0):

You can use template string like this：

```
   <a href={`https://tasks.office.com/credentinfotech.com/en-GB/Home/Planner#/plantaskboard?planId=${planid}&taskId=${id}`}></a>
```

References:
[Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)